# Live validation of input - JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, integer

I have an html form with the following line:

```
<input type="text" id="calcInput"/>
```

I want the user to be able to insert only positive integers (or 0), and if he enters a wrong value - I want to delete it.
Please notice - if the user enters 3 integer digits and then a non-integer character, I want to delete only the non-integer character.

Couldn't find any way to do it.

Your assist would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this will work.  The input event doesn't work in some older IE versions, and you have to use keypress/down etc.

```
$('#calcInput').on('input', function (e) {
    if ($(this).val()) //do your check here
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```